# How build against qt 5.3.1?

Tags: 14.10, qt, qt-creator, qt5, qmake

Trying to build qt-creator v3.2.2 from source on Ubuntu 14.10. Fails. Qmake can't find qt5.3.1

```
$ qmake -r
...
Project WARNING: QmlDesigner plugin has been disabled.
Project WARNING: This plugin requires Qt 5.3.1 or newer.
...

Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: designercomponents-private
```

Looks like qmake is built against qt5.3.0...

```
qmake -version
QMake version 3.0
Using Qt version 5.3.0 in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
```

..But some libraries appears to be linked against qt5.3.1:

```
$ apt-cache search libqt5 --names-only | awk '{ print $1 }' | xargs apt-cache show | grep -e 'Package\|Version' | grep 5.3.1 -B 1
Package: libqt5script5
Version: 5.3.1+dfsg-3ubuntu1

Package: libqt5scripttools5
Version: 5.3.1+dfsg-3ubuntu1

Package: libqt5xmlpatterns5
Version: 5.3.1-4ubuntu3

Package: libqt5xmlpatterns5-dev
Version: 5.3.1-4ubuntu3

Package: libqt5xmlpatterns5-private-dev
Version: 5.3.1-4ubuntu3

Package: libqt5websockets5
Version: 5.3.1-1ubuntu1

Package: libqt5websockets5-dev
Version: 5.3.1-1ubuntu1
```

What package am I missing that will allow me to use qt5.3.1? I haven't found a qt5base or qmake package that is of version 5.3.1.

The [14.10 Release Notes](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UtopicUnicorn/ReleaseNotes) only says "Qt updated to version 5.3", but the fact that some libraries appears to be of version 5.3.1 suggests to me that maybe 5.3.1 is supported.

Comment: Try to install all build dependencies using: `sudo apt-get build-dep qtcreator`

Comment: @Sneetsher You should write this as the answer because it is the answer and as such it should be accepted.

Comment: @rbaleksandar Thank you for remind, I have posted one.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes, it is hard to track build dependencies using `cmake`/`make` build errors. Better to install all build dependency used by release package using:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep qtcreator
```

This will save you much time, looking for just few addition dependencies if needed.